# Cannot send push from parse web console

Tags: push-notification, parse-platform

I have created an app, used the client/api keys in my android app to subscribe to a channel. I can see my device on the core/installations page but on the send push page, clicking on the send a push button doesn't do anything. Instead I see the message "No push notifications to display yet." and a button "learn how to send push notifications". I have to add that this is not my first app but a new one. What has changed?